# How do I completely wipe macbook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, partition

I was going to sell this macbook, so I needed to wipe it, however it doesn't seem like the recovery mode method will do everything, since I have 2 other partitions and I can't figure out how to merge them all to 1 partition with just mac os on it

Comment: You will need to describe what the other partitions are, name, description, etc. Unless it is a partition for Boot Camp or another OS or a partition that you specifically created, there is always more than one partition on a hard drive. It contains the recovery and boot partitions and contain no user data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To repartition your hard drive** (under macOS Sierra)

1. Open Disk Utility.
2. Select physical drive (most top level), not any of the partitions you have.
3. Click `Partition` button in the top row of buttons.
4. Select first of your two other partitions and press `-` button. This shall remove selected partition.
5. Repeat for the second of your other two partitions.
6. Select your first partition (where macOS is installed).
7. Drag resize control (press <kbd>⌘</kbd> for it to appear) or enter size manually to use all available space and press `Apply`.

[image]

Then follow these steps to prepare your Mac for sale.

**What to do before selling or giving away your Mac**

When preparing to sell or give away your Mac, you may want to erase some or all files from its hard drive. But first determine whether you should back up your computer and disable certain features and services. These steps show the recommended sequence of actions:

1. [Deauthorize your computer](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht6283) from iTunes, if applicable.
2. Back up your data using [Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427) or other backup methods.
3. If you use Find My Mac or other iCloud features on this Mac, complete these steps:

   1. [Back up your iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4910) content.
   2. Choose Apple Menu () > System Preferences, then click iCloud.
   3. Deselect the Find My Mac checkbox.
   4. Sign out of iCloud. When you sign out of iCloud, you're asked whether you want to remove iCloud data from your Mac. Removing iCloud data in this way makes sure that the data isn't also removed from any of your other devices that are using the same iCloud account.
4. Sign out of iMessage:

   1. In the Messages app, choose Preferences > Accounts.
   2. Select your iMessage account, then click Sign Out.
5. Reformat your hard drive and [reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).
6. After you reformat your hard drive and reinstall OS X, the computer restarts to a Welcome screen and asks you to choose a country or region. If you want to leave the Mac in an out-of-box state, don't continue with the setup of your system. Instead, press Command-Q to shut down the Mac. When the new owner turns on the Mac, the Setup Assistant will guide them through the setup process.